# Scala : Akka - multiple event buses for actorsystem or having prioritized events?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, event-bus

I have single ActorSystem, which has several subscribers to it's eventStream. Application may produce thousands of messages per second, and some of the messages are more important than the rest of. So they should be handled before all.

I found that every ActorSystem has single eventStream attached, thus it seems that I need to register same actor class with two (or more) ActorSystems, in order to receive important messages in dedicated eventStream.

Is this preferred approach, or there are some tricks for this task? May be classifiers can also tweak message priorities somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventStream is not a datastructure that holds events, it just routes events to subscribers, hence you should use PriorityMailbox for the listener actors, see the documentation for how to use priority mailboxes: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/dispatchers.html#Mailboxes