# Prioritizing message in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I've been attempting to follow the example from [Akka's docs on Dispatchers,](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/dispatchers.html#Mailboxes) which I found from [this post originally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183645/scala-akka-multiple-event-buses-for-actorsystem-or-having-prioritized-events).

After running a sample, I'm not convinced I have it setup correctly. I'm deviating from the example slightly. Instead of creating a **new** dispatcher entry in the application.conf, like the tutorial:

```
prio-dispatcher {
  mailbox-type = "akka.docs.dispatcher.DispatcherDocSpec$MyPrioMailbox"
}
```

I want to overwrite the default dispatcher for ALL actors in my application. Therefore, I've done this:

```
default-dispatcher
{
  mailbox-type = "LoggingPriorityMailbox"
}
```

And in Scala:

```
class LoggingPriorityMailbox
extends UnboundedPriorityMailbox(
  PriorityGenerator {
     case Debug(ts: Timestamp, s: String) => 10 // Lowest
     ...
     case otherwise                       =>  0 // Highest
  }) {}
```

I've turned on log-config-on-start setting and verified the mailbox-type is set properly for the default-dispatcher. So I suppose it's at least being configured properly... Am I missing something? As I've read elsewhere for priority mailboxes, it might just be the case that my testing hasn't overloaded the mailboxes and actors enough to allow them to prioritize.

Comment: You definitely don't want to change it for all actors. (hint: not all actors are created by you)

Comment: I understand that I don't create all actors in the system, but my thought is that all of those actors will pass messages that fall into the "otherwise" category and hence will have the highest priority. Essentially, I want to lower priority of certain messages that I define, and all else to deliver as-normal. Still not a good idea??

Comment: You are assuming that it retains insertion order for messages with the same priority.